# The arrow shown on the bicycle lane sign

Tags: canada, traffic

There is an arrow on the following [bicycle lane](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Canada_Reserved_Bicycle_Lane_Shoulder_Sign.svg) sign. What does it mean? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's better asked on https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your link says it's a *"Road sign **pointing to and indicating reserved lane for bicycles***" What's confusing about that?

Comment: An example in real life (Montreal street view): https://imgur.com/a/6klCNXb

Comment: Thank you so much for the example in real life! I was not sure about where the sign would be installed ~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simply indicates that the lane the arrow is pointing to is reserved for the use of bicycles.  Typically such a sign would be mounted on a pole near the curb, so that the arrow would point to the rightmost lane of the road.

[image]

Another version of the sign exists with an arrow pointing straight down.  This one is designed to be mounted on a cantilevered pole, so that it is directly above the bike lane in question.

[image]

> Where the bicycle lane is immediately adjacent
> to the curb, the ground-mounted version of the Reserved Bicycle Lane sign (Rb-84A OTM) should be installed. In cases where the bicycle lane is not adjacent to the curb, such as when a parking lane is present, the overhead mounted version of the Reserved Bicycle Lane sign (Rb-84 OTM) may be considered. If used, the overhead sign should be installed on a cantilever and centred above the designated lane, every 200 m or where visibility obstructions warrant. The cantilevered signs are not required after every intersection.

(All images and quotes taken from the [Ontario Traffic Manual](https://www.library.mto.gov.on.ca/SydneyPLUS/Sydney/Portal/default.aspx?component=AAAAIY&record=9c49ce44-e3b2-4389-91cd-5e9b67aad03d).)

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!